# One-To-One mapping in Grails

Tags: grails

Can someone please help me to figure out how to create domain classes for simple one-to-one mapping in grails !

let say we have 2 tables (oracle):

```
create table table_a(long_common_id_name number(5) primary key using index, 
                     notes varchar2(10 byte), 
                     update_seq number(3)not null );

create table table_b (long_common_id_name number(5) primary key using index, 
                      extra_notes varchar2(200 byte), 
                      update_seq number(3) not null);

alter table table_b add (constraint table_b_fk foreign key (long_common_id_name)
references table_a (long_common_id_name));
```

I created 2 domain classes:

```
class TableA {
    static mapping = {
        table 'table_a'
        columns {
            id                  column:'LONG_COMMON_ID_NAME'
            data                column:'NOTES'
            version             column:'UPDATE_SEQ'
        }
    }
    String data
    TableB extraData
}

class TableB {
    static mapping = {
        table 'table_b'
        columns {
            id                  column:'LONG_COMMON_ID_NAME'
            data                column:'EXTRA_NOTES'
            version             column:'UPDATE_SEQ'
        }
    }
    String data
}
```

This particular definition  is not correct. Grails (or Hibernate) builds an incorrect SQL for TableA :

```
select this_.LONG_COMMON_ID_NAME as LONG1_66_0_, this_.UPDATE_SEQ as UPDATE2_66_0_, this_.NOTES as NOTES66_0_, this_.extra_data_id as extra4_66_0_ from table_a this_
```

I've tried many things: belongsto , hasManey with unique but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, maybe someone will find it useful ...

I'm writing a quick web-ui against our legacy database, so instead of writing lots of SQLs to answer user questions I want automate it. I can not modify data structure and access through UI will be read only.

**Here is solution/workaround that I can live with:**

domain/TableA.groovy

```
class TableA {
    static mapping = {
        table 'table_a'
        columns {
            id                  column:'LONG_COMMON_ID_NAME'
            data                column:'NOTES'
            version             column:'UPDATE_SEQ'
        }
    }    
    // will manually handle persistence of TableB
    static transients = [ 'extraData' ]

    String data
    TableB extraData
}
```

---

domain/TableB.groovy

```
class TableB {
    static mapping = {
        table 'table_b'
        columns {
            id                  column:'LONG_COMMON_ID_NAME'
            data                column:'EXTRA_NOTES'
            version             column:'UPDATE_SEQ'
        }

        //actual id is copied from TableA after it is persisted
        id generator:'assigned'
    }

    static transients = [ "parent" ]

    String data
    TableA parent
}
```

---

the form in "views/tableA/create.gsp"  has input fields for TableA and TableB properties, so I will get data for TableA and TableB instances

---

In the  "controllers/TableAController.groovy" I manually update/delete/load TableB instance

```
def list = {    
   ...
   def rv = TableA.list( params)
   rv.each() { it.extraData = TableB.get(String.valueOf(it.id)) }
   ...
}

def show = {
   ....
   tableAInstance.extraData = TableB.get(tableAInstance.id)
   ...
}
def delete = {
   ...
   // delete tableB instance first before tableA
   def tb = TableB.get(tableAInstance.id)
   if (tb) tb.delete()

   tableAInstance.delete()
   ...
}

def save = {
   ....
   // after tableAInstance.save() call
   def tb = new TableB()
   tb.data = params.extraData?.data
   // copy id from tableA instance
   tb.id = tableAInstance.id
   tb.save()
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to set up the foreign key in that way? I'd expect a TABLE_B_ID column on TABLE_A.

Anyway, I think to do what you want you'll need to add a line to the mapping closure for extraData.

I'm not sure if this will play nicely with it being the primary key as well

e.g.

```
 static mapping = {
    extraData column:'LONG_COMMON_ID_NAME'
}
```

Comment: This is a legacy database I'm dealing with. 
I've tried what you've suggested before, it does not work. Here is the error message I get :
"Repeated column in mapping for entity: TableA column: LONG_COMMON_ID_NAME (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")"

Comment: Does moving the mapping lines outside of 'columns' make a difference? It doesn't appear to be needed according to the 1.1.1 documentation.

You might have to fall back to mapping the class using Hibenate xml: http://grails.org/Hibernate+Integration

Comment: declaring mapping column outside of 'columns' does not make any difference, same "Repeated column " error .

Comment: I'd try the hbm.xml approach then.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with leebuts, Grails will expect a separate FK ID field in the subsidiary table.

This table setup looks more like table-per-class inheritance.  You might be able to create a class TableB that *inherits* class TableA, where TableA contains Notes and TableB contains "data".  Grails will probably also want a discriminator column in TableB, but otherwise it looks like the tables would conform to Grails conventions for inheritance.

Take a look: http://grails.org/GORM+-+Mapping+DSL

Look for the way to turn off table-per-hierarchy